# Accessing imap with ssl using tor socket

Tags: sockets, ssl, imap, tor

Hi after installing tor in my centos 6.9 i used the following command to access imap with tor:

```
torify telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

the command works great it's access the imap with tor ip not my server ip.
The problem is when trying to do it in php using socks.

The following code is using the port 8118(privoxy port) to open an http tunnel in tor port 9050:

```
$aStreamContextSettings = array(
        'http' => array(
            'proxy' => '127.0.0.1:8118'
        )
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_host' => false,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );

    $rStreamContext = \stream_context_create($aStreamContextSettings);

    $connect = \stream_socket_client('ssl://imap.gmail.com:993',0, "", 10, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $rStreamContext);
```

it's not working.

i also have tried to bind to tor but it's returning:

> stream_socket_client(): failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:9050', system said: Address already in use

```
$aStreamContextSettings = array(
        'socket' => array(
            'bindto' => '127.0.0.1:9050',
        ),
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_host' => false,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
```

i hope someone can figure out where is the problem in my code

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Privoxy is an HTTP proxy that can use Tor's SOCKS proxy as an upstream so that HTTP applications that don't support SOCKS can still use Tor.

Since you're trying to open an IMAP connection, Privoxy is not going to work since it expects to speak HTTP, not IMAP.

You basically need to find an IMAP library that supports SOCKS5.  If cURL is built with imap support, it should work as well.

Since PHP sockets don't support SOCKS, another option is to use a general purpose SOCKS client and then use it to read/write from the remote IMAP server.  For that, have a look at [bitaurora/phsocks](https://github.com/bitaurora/phsocks).

EDIT: Depending on what you're trying to do, cURL may still be your best option.  You'll absolutely want to use SSL/TLS when connecting to IMAP and if you use the SOCKS client, you'd have to implement TLS manually.

Here is an IMAP cURL example in PHP:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'imaps://imap.gmail.com:993');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username@gmail.com:12345');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
/*
// some fetches don't return everything with RETURNTRANSFER.
// instead, you'll have to use the header function to get the data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($ch, $data) {
    echo $data;
    return strlen($data);
});
*/

$cmd = 'select INBOX';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $cmd);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

if ($res === false) {
    // login failed or possible server connection error
}

var_dump($res, curl_getinfo($ch)); exit;

// need the headerfunction here to get the header info
$cmd = 'FETCH 1:10 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT DATE FROM)])';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $cmd);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($res);
```

This works with Gmail.  If the account has two-factor auth enabled, you can't login with a regular password.  You'll need to generate an app password and use that for the password.